# Two integration problems

Tags: integration, limits

1. Find out **if** this limit exists: $$\lim_{y\to 0}\int_0^1\frac{x e^{\frac{-x^2}{y^2}}}{y^2}dx$$
2. Evaluate $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\arctan(a \tan(x))}{\tan(x)}$$

I'm a bit lost with these two problems. I tried to use some change of variables in the second one, but it didn't work the way I tried. As for the first one I don't even know what to start with, though it seems quite interesting. I'd grateful for any help!

I apologize in advance for possibly being unclear as I'm non-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, note that
$$0 < \int_0^1 \dfrac{x e^{-x^2/y^2}}{y^2} dx < \int_0^1 \dfrac{x}{y^2 \left(1+\dfrac{x^2}{y^2} \right)} dx = \int_0^1 \dfrac{x}{y^2+x^2} dx$$ Now you should be able to proceed and conclude the limit.

---

For the second one, let
$$I(a) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\arctan(a \tan(x))}{\tan(x)}dx$$
We then have
$$I'(a) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dx}{1+a^2 \tan^2(x)} = \dfrac{\pi}{2a+2}$$
Hence, we get that (since $I(0)=1$)
$$I(a) = \dfrac{\pi}2 \log(1+a)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it's clear now!

Comment: @Michael Differentiation under integral is a powerful trick and in general, swapping two operations is a very powerful trick.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, we can integrate explicitly, using the substitution $u=-\frac{x^2}{y^2}$. Then $du=-\frac{2x}{y^2}\,dx$, and therefore $x\,dx=-\frac{y^2}{2}\,du$.

Substitute. We get some cancellation, and arrive at the integral
$$\int_0^{-y^2} -\frac{1}{2}e^u \,du.$$
Integrate: we get $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-y^2})$. The limit is now easy to calculate.